# Graph API not responding

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using graph API to get the feed post.
https://graph.facebook.com/128172073865656/feed?limit=200
but it is showing exception

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}.
Could any one please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you need to obtain and supply an access token with your request.

In particular, the Graph API connections that you're trying to load have been changed recently, and now require an `access_token`, where they previously did not.

See the Facebook Developer Blog, posts on this:

- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/ - Notification of change in requirements.
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/ - Confirmation that the changes are now live.